# Poetry error while trying to install Mediapipe

Tags: python, python-poetry

I am trying to install mediapipe, opencv, etc. with poetry using `poetry add <package>` then doing `poetry install`. The problem comes when it gets to installing pillow as it fails to install it but after printing the error message it just stops(as in nothing is printing, nothing in the background etc.). I have tried to run it multiple times but it always fails on pillow.

Any Help would be great!

Heres a link to the error message : https://pastebin.com/K7jYQ4ct

Comment: Looks like there is a very old version of `setuptools` in your venv. Try updating this first using `pip`.

Comment: Unfortunately this has only gotten rid of the error about `setuptools` and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and found the fix [here](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1985#issuecomment-703266012). My issue was that my poetry project had the same name as the package (mediapipe in this example). Recreating the poetry project with a different name fixed it.